# Find the truth values of the following?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

let $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ be the statements $x^3<50$ and $x+2<5$ respecively. Find the truth values of the following, where the domain consists of all real numbers.

(1) $\exists x>0 P(x)$

(2) $\forall x>0 (\neg Q(x))$

**My Try**

When I take cubic root i can simplify the inequality as $x<3.68$, So the statement is true and there exist positive real numbers which satisfy the inequality. How can I construct the answer to this question because I'm new to this topic? Please help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that an existential statement such as $(1)$ is true, you just need a single "witness."  So it's enough to note that $P(1)$ is true and that $1 \gt 0$.

Similarly, to show that a universal statement such as $(2)$ is false, it's enough to find a single counterexample.  So it's enough to note that $Q(1)$ is true and $1 \gt 0$.